# Attested technical term for graph which can be drawn in plane with straight edges, such that group of symmetries of drawing is group of automorphisms?

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, reference-request

**Question.** Is there an attested technical term in the graph-theoretic literature for 'undirected simple graph which admits at least one line-crossing-tolerant-straight-line-embedding into $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose set-wise stabilizer subgroup within the group of [Euclidean plane isometries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_plane_isometry) is isomorphic as an abstract group to the graph's automorphism group'?

For what of a usual term, let us call such a graph an 'appropriately drawable' graph.

**Remark.**

- The term 'crossing-tolerant-straight-line-embedding' means what it says: first realize the abstract graph as a 1-dimensional geometric simplicial complex $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^3$, then choose a continuous map $\rho\colon X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ having the property that it is injective on the set of vertices of $X$ and that each edge of $X$ is mapped to a straight line in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The class of all subsets of the form $\mathrm{image}(\rho)$ with such a $\rho$ is the class of all subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which are eligible when deciding whether $G$ is 'appropriately drawable'. Note that intersections of the line segments are not forbidden.
- While I am currently mostly interested in planar graphs when it comes to the above, the above definition of course makes sense for non-planar graphs as well, and it seems to me that if one introduces this class of graphs, one should not restrict to planar graphs, since drawings of graphs with crossings are quite common, and even studied per se in the literature.
- The above is such a natural concept that I do not believe it was not isolated somewhere in the literature, yet I am not aware of it. Intuitively, these are the graphs which can be drawn with straight lines as the edges such that the symmetries of the resulting picture already are *all* the symmetries that the graph has.
- An example of an 'appropriately drawable' graph is the [Tutte graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_graph).  If it is drawn like on the current Wikipedia page, the group of the three rotational symmetries of the picture is the stabilizer subgroup of the picture (as a point-set) inside the group $E(2)$ of Euclidean symmetries of the plane. (Note in particular that this drawing of the Tutte graph does not have reflection symmetries.)